# How can I reshape this array?

Tags: machine-learning, python, deep-learning, numpy, reshape

I have few difficulties in picking values from an array. Here is a simplified version of the concerned part of the code. (If you would like to put the whole code please mention it)

```
n=2
m=8
test= test[:,-n*m:] 
test=test.reshape(test.shape[0],n,m)
```

So, I end up with :

```
test.shape= (350, 2, 8)
```

when I run the code I've got this:

```
array([[[0.01911469, 0.32352942, 0.18032786, ..., 0.006101  ,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.01810865, 0.32352942, 0.18032786, ..., 0.006101  ,
         0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.01810865, 0.32352942, 0.18032786, ..., 0.006101  ,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.01710262, 0.32352942, 0.1967213 , ..., 0.01297103,
         0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.01710262, 0.32352942, 0.1967213 , ..., 0.01297103,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.01408451, 0.32352942, 0.18032786, ..., 0.00763907,
         0.        , 0.        ]],

       ...,

       [[0.01006036, 0.2647059 , 0.26229507, ..., 0.40558836,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.01006036, 0.2647059 , 0.26229507, ..., 0.41399646,
         0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.01006036, 0.2647059 , 0.26229507, ..., 0.41399646,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.00804829, 0.2647059 , 0.24590163, ..., 0.4208665 ,
         0.        , 0.        ]],

       [[0.00804829, 0.2647059 , 0.24590163, ..., 0.4208665 ,
         0.        , 0.        ],
        [0.01207243, 0.2794118 , 0.26229507, ..., 0.42621556,
         0.        , 0.        ]]], dtype=float32)
```

My question is how can I get only the values of the first columns like this:

```
array([[0.01911469],
       [0.01810865],
       [0.01810865],
       [0.01710262],
       [0.01710262],
       [0.01408451],
        ...,
       [0.01006036],
       [0.01006036], 
       [0.01006036],
       [0.00804829],
       [0.00804829],
       [0.01207243]], dtype=float32)
```

I have tried this:

```
test=test[:,:,:1]
```

but I've got this instead of what I'm looking for:

```
array([[[0.01911469],
        [0.01810865]],

       [[0.01810865],
        [0.01710262]],

       [[0.01710262],
        [0.01408451]],

       ...,

       [[0.01006036],
        [0.01006036]],

       [[0.01006036],
        [0.00804829]],

       [[0.00804829],
        [0.01207243]]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. As you want all first value of zeroth dimension.

```
test=test[:,0,0]
```